Fix first and second derivatives at two points: is convexity possible?
Consider a convex and smooth (or at least $C^2$) function $f$ such that:

$f(x)>0$ for  $x\in (a,b)$

$f'(x)>0$ for  $x\in (a,b)$

$f''(x)>0$ for  $x\in (a,b)$


Now, we are given an interval $[x_1,x_2] \subset(a,b)$, namely $a<x_1<x_2<b$, together with 6 real numbers: $(f_1,f'_1,f''_1,f_2,f'_2,f''_2)$, the values of $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ at $x_1$ and $x_2$.
Question: Under what conditions the 6 numbers $(f_1,f'_1,f''_1,f_2,f'_2,f''_2)$ are inconsistent with the three properties of $f$ listed above?
Partial answer: We aim to determine the constraints the 6 numbers must satisfy. For example, all the 6 numbers $(f_1,f'_1,f''_1,f_2,f'_2,f''_2)$ must be positive. However, this is not enough: we should also ask
$$
f'_1< \frac{f_2-f_1}{x_2-x_1} <f'_2
$$
meaning that the average slope over $(x_1,x_2)$ lies between the slopes at the endpoints of the interval.
My claim is that the requirement
$$
0<f_1<f_2 \qquad \& \qquad 
0<f'_1< \frac{f_2-f_1}{x_2-x_1} <f'_2
\qquad \& \qquad f''_{1,2}>0
$$
is such that: "if it is not respected, then it is impossible to find an $f$ satisfying the three wanted properties; if it is respected, then it is possible to find an $f$ satisfying the three wanted properties". Provided that my intuition is correct, how to prove this statement rigorously? Otherwise, should we impose a more stringent constraint on the 6 numbers?

You should also add $f_1''>0$ and $f_2''>0$ but I guess that's all the restrictions, i.e., given six numbers satisfying these restrictions, I think you can construct a convex function $f$ that satisfies the first three requirements.

@Pranay you are right, I forgot about it but it's part of the "trivial" requests. I edit the question, thank you for spotting this!

@lonzaleggiera This may be very interesting but I can not "visualize" it. Also, it is a bit strange to write something like $f_1'<\frac{f_2''-f_1''}{x_2-x_1}<f_2' $ because it does not fit "dimensional analysis" (imaging that $f$ is some physical quantity and $x$ another one).

As far I understand, according to the mean value Lagrange's theorem, we should have $\frac{f_2-f_1}{x_2-x_1}=f'(x_3)$. The equality $\frac{f''_2-f''_1}{x_2-x_1}=f'(x_3)$ fails, for instance when $f(x)=x^2$ and $x_1>0$, because then its left-hand side of the is $0$, whereas its right-hand side is $2x_3>0$.

@Quillo My  apologies for the brain fart.  What you get from the mean value theorem is $\ \frac{f_2'-f_1'}{x_2-x_1}=f''(x_3)\ ,$ not what I wrote.  But since all you know about$\ f''\  $ is that  it's positive,  these inequalities  don't  impose any more restrictions than what you already know —namely $\  f_2'> f_1'\  .$

Does $f=e^x$ fulfill the requirements?

@Joako of course yes, as all the convex functions I can think of.

Regarding the recent edit: if any of those restrictions is not satisfied, then clearly such an $f$ cannot exist, so the nontrivial direction is the other direction, i.e., constructing a strictly positive convex function whose first and second derivatives are also strictly positive and attains the given six values. I was trying to do this using bump functions to construct an appropriate $f''$ but it got very complicated when I got to $f$.

@Pranay you are right, I also got stuck in the "other direction". However, I decided to make this edit for extra clarity (before I was just asking for "the most general set of inequalities", or something like that, that was a bit of a fuzzy terminology).

We can construct smooth functions $g$ with $g, g', g'' > 0$ and all of the following limiting behaviors for their tuples $T[g(x)] = (g(x_1), g'(x_1), g''(x_1), g(x_2), g'(x_2), g''(x_2))$ as $ε → 0$:
\begin{align*}
T\left[1 + ε\left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}\right)\right] &→ (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), \\
T\left[x - x_1 + ε + \sqrt{ε^4 + (x - x_1 + ε)^2}\right] &→ (0, 2, 0, 2(x_2 - x_1), 2, 0), \\
T\left[x - x_1 - ε + \sqrt{ε^4 + (x - x_1 - ε)^2}\right] &→ (0, 0, 0, 2(x_2 - x_1), 2, 0), \\
T\left[x - x_2 + ε + \sqrt{ε^4 + (x - x_2 + ε)^2}\right] &→ (0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), \\
T\left[ε\left((x - x_1) + \sqrt{ε^2 + (x - x_1)^2}\right)\right] &→ (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), \\
T\left[ε\left((x - x_2) + \sqrt{ε^2 + (x - x_2)^2}\right)\right] &→ (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
\end{align*}
Any tuple $t = (f_1, f'_1, f''_1, f_2, f'_2, f''_2)$ satisfying the given requirements is a positive linear combination of the above six limiting tuples. Because the six limiting tuples span all of $\mathbb R^6$ as vectors, their positive combinations are an open set in $\mathbb R^6$. So $t$ is also a positive linear combination of the six actual tuples for sufficiently small $ε$, and we can construct the desired function $f$ as the same positive linear combination of the above functions $g$.

+1 This is a very interesting approach, how did you find the 6 limiting behaviours? Also, if I interpret this answer correctly it validates my partial answer, right? Sorry for the possibly trivial questions.

@Quillo There’s no magic, you just evaluate the derivatives algebraically and take the limit.

I see the following potential problem when you pass from "positive linear combination of the limiting tuples" to "positive linear combination of actual tuples". Consider the following example : $A(\varepsilon)=(-1,\varepsilon)$ and $B(\varepsilon)=(1,\varepsilon)$. When $\varepsilon \to 0$, $A(\varepsilon) \to A_\infty=(-1,0)$ and   $B(\varepsilon) \to B_\infty=(1,0)$. Now the origin is a positive linear combination of $A_\infty$ and $B_\infty$, but it is not a positive linear combination of $A(\varepsilon)$ and $B(\varepsilon)$, for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$.

@AndersKaseorg thank you for the clarification but why considering things like $1 + \epsilon \left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}\right)$ in the first place? Isn't this a bit arbitrary? (This "epsilon" expression is what I meant by limiting behaviour, not the actual 6-tuples, sorry for the sloppy question)

@EwanDelanoy Good question, but such a case is impossible when the limiting tuples span the whole space as vectors, because their positive combinations are an open set. I’ll note this in the answer, thanks.

@Quillo Yes, it’s arbitrary. This is one possible construction of many, as is often the case in mathematics—a problem that forces you down exactly one solution path is usually a less interesting problem! I chose this construction because using functions that graph a branch of a hyperbola made it easy to reason about them, both geometrically and algebraically.
